# Warning: Using contract member "balance" inherited from the address type is deprecated

Tags: solidity, remix

`browser/ballot.sol:61:13: Warning: Using contract member "balance" inherited from the address type is deprecated. Convert the contract to "address" type to access the member.
    require(this.balance >= 1000000000000000);`

What does it mean "convert the contract to address" type? How do I get the address of `this`?

I got this error in 0.4.21 of Solidity through Remix browser.

Answer (score 14):

Try `require(address(this).balance >= 1000000000000000)`

Answer (score 1):

Just assign 'this' to a local variable

```
address myAddress = this;
require(myAddress.balance >= 1000000000000000);
```

Answer (score 0):

using

```
address(this).balance
```

is the correct approach